# Writing a table of national park data

Tags: python, csv, geospatial, arcpy

I'm working to produce a Lookup table using the [Arcpy](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy/a-quick-tour-of-arcpy.htm) module that contains descriptive statistics for US National Parks.

The original data, found in `tbl`, has 12 million records.

Using a Search Cursor,

```
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(tbl, ("*"), where_clause) as cursor:
                for row in cursor:
```

I am working through the original data and compiling these statistics using [numpy.percentile](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/reference/generated/numpy.percentile.html).

The portion of the code that I am seeking help with improving is the next section, where, for each Park, Year, and Month, I gather those statistics into lists, then create a new record from the lists, then delete the list at the end of each loop.

```
    parkLatList = []
    parkLongList = []
    numPplList = []
    qnumList = []
    qldtList = []
    qdurList = []
    qdisList = []
    numResList = []
    sumDurList = []
    persNightList = []
    rowCount = 0

    with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(tbl, ("*"), where_clause) as cursor:
        for row in cursor:

            numPplList.append(int(row[12]))
            parkLatList.append(float(row[15]))
            parkLongList.append(float(row[16]))
            qnumList.append(int(row[12]))
            qldtList.append(int(row[13]))
            qdurList.append(int(row[14]))
            qdisList.append(float(row[19]))
            numResList.append(int(len(row)))
            sumDurList.append(int(row[14]))
            rowCount += 1


        parkLat = parkLatList[0]
        parkLong = parkLongList[0]
        qnum25 = float(np.percentile(qnumList, 25))
        qnum50 = float(np.percentile(qnumList, 50))
        qnum75 = float(np.percentile(qnumList, 75))
        qldt25 = float(np.percentile(qldtList, 25))
        qldt50 = float(np.percentile(qldtList, 50))
        qldt75 = float(np.percentile(qldtList, 75))
        qdur25 = float(np.percentile(qdurList, 25))
        qdur50 = float(np.percentile(qdurList, 50))
        qdur75 = float(np.percentile(qdurList, 75))
        qdis25 = float(np.percentile(qdisList, 25))
        qdis50 = float(np.percentile(qdisList, 50))
        qdis75 = float(np.percentile(qdisList, 75))
        numRes = rowCount
        sumDur = int(np.sum(sumDurList))
        persNight = int(np.sum(sumDurList)) * int(np.sum(numPplList))

        writer.writerow([park, year, month,
                         parkLat, parkLong,
                         qnum25, qnum50, qnum75,
                         qldt25, qldt50, qldt75,
                         qdur25, qdur50, qdur75,
                         qdis25, qdis50, qdis75,
                         numRes, sumDur, persNight])

        del parkLatList
        del parkLongList
        del numPplList
        del qnumList
        del qldtList
        del qdurList
        del qdisList
        del numResList
        del sumDurList
        del persNightList
```

The end goal is to produce a table that has one row for each Park, Year and Month. So the out table will look something like:

```
+------------+---------+------------+---------+
|    Park    |  Year   |   Month    |  qsum25 |
+------------+---------+------------+---------+
| Acadia Ntl | 2007    |     1      |   3.25  |
| Acadia Ntl | 2007    |     2      |   2.75  |
+------------+---------+------------+---------+
```

Is there a more efficient way to collect these descriptive statistics, then add them to a single row, then ensure a list is cleared after an iteration than what I currently have written?

Apologies for the lack of list comprehension - I usually program in R...

```
import arcpy
import csv
import os
import numpy as np
from datetime import date


arcpy.env.workspace = "F:\\Parks_Paper\\QNBT\\Aggregation.gdb"

tbl = arcpy.ListTables("*")[0]
fieldList = arcpy.ListFields(tbl)

def unique_values(table, field):
    with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(table, [field]) as cursor:
        return sorted({row[0] for row in cursor})

print "getting unique parks..."
with open('parks.txt') as f:
    parks = f.read().splitlines()
print "unique parks received..."

years = [2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016]
months =[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]


filename = 'F:\\Parks_Paper\\QNBT\\Analysis\\lookup.csv'
try:
    os.remove(filename)
except OSError:
    pass

dataCSV = open(filename, 'wb')
writer = csv.writer(dataCSV, dialect="excel")
writer.writerow(['Park', 'Year', 'Month', 'parklat', 'parklon',
                 'qnum25', 'qnum50', 'qnum75',
                 'qldt25', 'qldt50', 'qldt75',
                 'qdur25', 'qdur50', 'qdur75',
                 'qdis25', 'qdis50', 'qdis75',
                 'numres', 'sumdur', 'persnight'])

for park in parks:
    for year in years:
        for month in months:
            print "Processing.... \n Park: {0} \n Year: {1} \n Month: {2}".format(park, year, month)
            where_clause = """"Park" = '{0}' AND "Year" = {1} AND "Month" = {2}""".format(park, year, month)

            parkLatList = []
            parkLongList = []
            numPplList = []
            qnumList = []
            qldtList = []
            qdurList = []
            qdisList = []
            numResList = []
            sumDurList = []
            persNightList = []
            rowCount = 0

            with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(tbl, ("*"), where_clause) as cursor:
                for row in cursor:

                    numPplList.append(int(row[12]))
                    parkLatList.append(float(row[15]))
                    parkLongList.append(float(row[16]))
                    qnumList.append(int(row[12]))
                    qldtList.append(int(row[13]))
                    qdurList.append(int(row[14]))
                    qdisList.append(float(row[19]))
                    numResList.append(int(len(row)))
                    sumDurList.append(int(row[14]))
                    rowCount += 1


                parkLat = parkLatList[0]
                parkLong = parkLongList[0]
                qnum25 = float(np.percentile(qnumList, 25))
                qnum50 = float(np.percentile(qnumList, 50))
                qnum75 = float(np.percentile(qnumList, 75))
                qldt25 = float(np.percentile(qldtList, 25))
                qldt50 = float(np.percentile(qldtList, 50))
                qldt75 = float(np.percentile(qldtList, 75))
                qdur25 = float(np.percentile(qdurList, 25))
                qdur50 = float(np.percentile(qdurList, 50))
                qdur75 = float(np.percentile(qdurList, 75))
                qdis25 = float(np.percentile(qdisList, 25))
                qdis50 = float(np.percentile(qdisList, 50))
                qdis75 = float(np.percentile(qdisList, 75))
                numRes = rowCount
                sumDur = int(np.sum(sumDurList))
                persNight = int(np.sum(sumDurList)) * int(np.sum(numPplList))

                writer.writerow([park, year, month,
                                 parkLat, parkLong,
                                 qnum25, qnum50, qnum75,
                                 qldt25, qldt50, qldt75,
                                 qdur25, qdur50, qdur75,
                                 qdis25, qdis50, qdis75,
                                 numRes, sumDur, persNight])

                del parkLatList
                del parkLongList
                del numPplList
                del qnumList
                del qldtList
                del qdurList
                del qdisList
                del numResList
                del sumDurList
                del persNightList

f.close()
```

Comment: It's a little bit confusing when you post the same code twice and the first snippet looks exactly like the code in the full function. I suggest only leaving the complete code and removing the first part. Instead you can mark where this part starts with a comment.